# How to read a string from user input in C, put in array and print

Tags: c, arrays, input, user-input

I'm fairly new to C and I've read a few chapters of a C book I have and now I have to make an assignment but I am all confused hope someone can help me out.

I have to read 2 strings from user (char arrays) input with a max length of 100 characters and convert them to capital letters and print them out with a newline \n after each word.

Until now I have this:

```
int main() {
char chars[100];
int i = 0;
char str1;
char str2;
int j = 0;

scanf("\n %c", str1);
scanf("\n %c", str2);


while (str1[i] != '\0') {

    chars[i] = str1[i];
    toupper(chars[i]);
    printf(chars[i]);
    i++;

}

while (str2[j] != '\0') {

    chars[j] = str2[j];
    toupper(chars[j]);
    printf(chars[j]);
    j++;

}


return 0;
}
```

after it takes the 2 inputs from user, it says stops running and says run failed.

Comment: `str1` and `str2` should be array

Comment: ill try that... didn't make any difference as it still stops after the input

Comment: Your compiler didn't give any warnings, right? Oh wait noez...

Comment: @user1842140 Hint: you want to use `fgets()`. Google its documentation. **Stay far away from `scanf()`.**

Comment: Isn't it possible without     fgets() ? Not sure if I am supposed to use it.

Comment: `char chars[100]` is big enough for a maximum input of 99 characters and then a terminating `\0`.  You may want to increase your buffer size by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your immediate problem:

```
scanf("\n %c", str1);
```

This format string tells `scanf` to read some amount of whitespace followed by a single character, which is to be stored in `str1`.

@H2CO3 is right: `scanf` is almost never the right answer for reading input from the user. It performs no bounds checking and is too finicky about the format of user input; one unexpected character will completely confuse it. You are very strongly encouraged to use `fgets` instead if at all possible:

```
fgets(str1, 100, stdin);
```

If you are not allowed to do this, you should ask your professor why not. Seriously.

If you absolutely must use `scanf` to read input here, you can do it the way @user2479209 described in their answer.

There is another problem with your program, which is that `toupper(chars[i])` will not change the value stored in `chars[i]`. You have to assign the result of `toupper` back to the array explicitly, e.g.:

```
chars[i] = toupper(chars[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

change str1 and str2 to array. use %100[^\n] in first two scanf's.It's a regular expression trick to read strings with spaces.read about it.

```
char str1[101];
char str2[101];
scanf("%100[^\n]",str1);
scanf("%100[^\n]",str2);
```

This will take in two strings.hit enter after entering the first string to enter the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also use `scanf_s` (secure `scanf`) and collect both strings input by user in one shot. You can also define the array size as a symbolic constant for flexibility, on the top of your program, outside of `main` and below the `#include` preprocesor directives.

```
// Symbolic constants
#define SIZE 101

char str1[SIZE];
char str2[SIZE];
scanf_s("%100s%100s", str1, SIZE, str2, SIZE);
```

Alternatively:

```
scanf_s("%100s", str1, SIZE);
scanf_s("%100s", str2, SIZE);
```

I think that, if you don't want to do `#define SIZE 101`, you can also do:

```
scanf_s("%100s", str1, 101);
scanf_s("%100s", str2, 101);
```

I'm new to C so feel free to improve this answer.

Comment: Your own question would be better asked as a separate question.